# encapsulate repeated send/responses to the same Dart isolate within a single asyncronous function

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Is it possible to encapsulate repeated send/responses to the same dart isolate within a single asynchronous function?

Background:

In order to design a convenient API, I would like to have a function asynchronously return the result generated by an isolate, e.g.

```
var ans = await askIsolate(isolateArgs);
```

This works fine if I directly use the response generated by a spawnUri call, e.g

```
Future<String> askIsolate(Map<String,dynamic> isolateArgs) {

ReceivePort response = new ReceivePort();
var uri = Uri.parse(ISOLATE_URI);

Future<Isolate> remote = Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [JSON.encode(isolateArgs)], response.sendPort);
return remote.then((i) => response.first)
               .catchError((e) { print("Failed to spawn isolate"); })
               .then((msg) => msg.toString());
}
```

The downside of the above approach, however, is that if I need to repeatedly call askIsolate, the isolate must be spawned each time.

I would instead like to communicate with a running isolate, which is certainly possible by having the isolate return a sendPort to the caller.  But I believe since the [2013 Isolate refactoring](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/EVUMkZXFXtY)  , this requires the caller to listen to subsequent messages on the receivePort, making encapsulation within a single async function impossible.

Is there some mechanism to accomplish this that I'm missing?

Comment: It's a while I played with isolates. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/isolate is supposed to provide a nice API to isolates. I assume it's worth having a closer look.

Comment: The `IsolateRunner` in `package:isolate` is intended for calling a function in a spawned isolate more than once. I think it will work for this problem: `var runner = await IsolateRunner.spawn(); for (var arg in something) }{ ... await runner.run(queryFunction, arg); ... } await runner.close();`

Comment: Another option is to have a service isolate running, but instead of having it return the result on the same port each time, each request can send its own `SendPort` with it. Then each request can create a `ResponsePort` and return the `first` getter of that for the response: `Future askIsolate(isolateArgs) { var p = new ReceivePort(); runningIsolatePort.send([isolateArgs, p.sendPort]); return p.first; }`.

Comment: I haven't been successful in getting IsolateRunner to work well in spawnURI situation.  I need to be able to call and exec a known method on an external dart script.  I know you can manually wrap an Isolate with IsolateRunner, but I've failed to see how I can utilize IsolateRunner.run to exec external methods.

However, lrn's second suggestion appears to work well.  I'll finish some tests and post a full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick working example based on lrn's comment above follows.  The example initializes an isolate via spawnURI, and then communicates with the isolate by passing a new ReceivePort upon which a reply is expected.  This allows the askIsolate to directly return a response from a running spawnURI isolate.

Note error handling has been omitted for clarity.

**Isolate code:**

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;

main(List<String> initArgs, SendPort replyTo) async {
  ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();
  replyTo.send(receivePort.sendPort);

  receivePort.listen((List<dynamic> callArgs) async {
    SendPort thisResponsePort = callArgs.removeLast(); //last arg must be the offered sendport
    thisResponsePort.send("Map values: " + JSON.decode(callArgs[0]).values.join(","));
  });
}
```

**Calling code:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:convert';


const String ISOLATE_URI = "http://localhost/isolates/test_iso.dart";
SendPort isolateSendPort = null;

Future<SendPort> initIsolate(Uri uri) async {
    ReceivePort response = new ReceivePort();
    await Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [], response.sendPort, errorsAreFatal: true);
    print("Isolate spawned from $ISOLATE_URI");
    return await response.first;
}


Future<dynamic> askIsolate(Map<String,String> args) async {
  if (isolateSendPort == null) {
    print("ERROR: Isolate has not yet been spawned");
    isolateSendPort = await initIsolate(Uri.parse(ISOLATE_URI)); //try again
  }

  //Send args to the isolate, along with a receiveport upon which we listen for first response 
  ReceivePort response = new ReceivePort();
  isolateSendPort.send([JSON.encode(args), response.sendPort]);
  return await response.first;
}

main() async {
  isolateSendPort = await initIsolate(Uri.parse(ISOLATE_URI));

  askIsolate({ 'foo':'bar', 'biz':'baz'}).then(print);
  askIsolate({ 'zab':'zib', 'rab':'oof'}).then(print);
  askIsolate({ 'One':'Thanks', 'Two':'lrn'}).then(print);
}
```

**Output**

```
Isolate spawned from http://localhost/isolates/test_iso.dart
Map values: bar,baz
Map values: zib,oof
Map values: Thanks,lrn
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depend on how you intend to use the isolate

- Do you intend to keep it running indefinitely, sending it inputs and expecting to receive answers asynchronously?
- Do you want to send the isolate many (but finite) inputs at once, expect to receive answers asynchronously, then close the isolate?

I'm guessing the latter, and your `askIsolate()` function needs to immediately return a `Future` than completes when it receives all the answers.

The `await for` loop can be used to listen to a stream and consume events until it closes.

I'm not familiar with isolates, so I hope this is OK, I have not tested it. I've assumed that the isolate terminates and response closes.

```
String askIsolate(Map<String,dynamic> isolateArgs) async {

  ReceivePort response = new ReceivePort();
  var uri = Uri.parse(ISOLATE_URI);

  Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [JSON.encode(isolateArgs)], response.sendPort)
    .catchError((e)) {
     throw ...;
   });

  List<String> answers = new List<String>;

  await for(var answer in response) {
    out.add(answer.toString());
  }

  return answers;
}
```

Note:

- `response` is the stream you are listening to for answers. It's created *before* spawning the isolate so you don't need to (and probably should not) wait for the isolate future to complete before listening to it.
- I made `askIsolate()` async because that makes it very easy to immediately return a future which completes when the function returns - without all that tedious mucking about with `.then(...)` chains, which I personally find confusing and hard to read.

BTW, your original `then(...).catchError(...)` style code would be better written like this:

```
  Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [JSON.encode(isolateArgs)], response.sendPort)
    .catchError((e) { ... });

   return response.first)
     .then((msg) => msg.toString());
```

I believe that delaying attaching a catchError handler to the line after the isolate's creation might allow the future to complete with an error *before* the handler is in place.

See: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/futures-and-error-handling/#potential-problem-failing-to-register-error-handlers-early .

Comment: Actually, the former in your two bullets is what I'd like.  Thank you for the catch on the then(...).catchError(...) issue!

Comment: Do you want to implement a function that sends an input to an isolate, and returns a future that completes when the isolate sends back a result, which you can call repeatedly?

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend looking at `IsolateRunner` in `package:isolate`, it is intended to solve problems like this - calling a function in the same isolate several times instead of just once when the isolate is created.

If you don't want that, there are other, more primitive, options

Async functions can wait on futures or streams and a `ReceivePort` is a stream. 
For a quick hack, you can probably do something with an `await for` on the response stream, but it won't be very convenient.

Wrapping the `ReceivePort` in a `StreamQueue` from `package:async` is a better choice. That allows you to convert the individual events into futures. Something like:

```dart
myFunc() async {  
  var responses = new ReceivePort();
  var queue = new StreamQueue(responses);
  // queryFunction sends its own SendPort on the port you pass to it.
  var isolate = await isolate.spawn(queryFunction, [], responses.sendPort);
  var queryPort = await queue.next();
  for (var something in somethingToDo) {
    queryPort.send(something);
    var response = await queue.next();
    doSomethingWithIt(response);
  }
  queryPort.send("shutdown command");  
  // or isolate.kill(), but it's better to shut down cleanly.
  responses.close();  // Don't forget to close the receive port.
}
```